# How do I set the image source to a Picture from 'Pictures' library?

Tags: javascript, html, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm currently using a File Picker to get a picture, using the example code from the Quickstart Tutorial: [Accessing files with file pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465199.aspx) to select the picture.

This works fine, the problem comes when I try to use the selected image on screen, using an HTML img tag.

```
openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(
    function (file) {
        if (file) {
            var picture = document.getElementById("pictureId");
            picture.src = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(file.path);
        }
    }
);
```

The picture's `file.path` is in the form of `C:\Users\<user>\Pictures\example.jpg`

I've tried using:

- `picture.src = file.path`
- `picture.src = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(file.path)`

I've also tried copying the path directly to the `<img>` tag to make sure it's not a screen refresh issue, but it still doesn't load.

The corresponding HTML, if relevant, is:

```
<div>
    <img id="pictureId" class="pictureClass" src="" />
    <button id="addPictureButton" class="">Add Picture</button>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435808/windows-8-app-html-javascript-alternate-way-to-show-image-from-picture-lib?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try one of the following

- `picture.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);`
  OR
- `picture.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);`

## References

- createObjectURL method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh453196
- [How can I draw an image from the HTML5 File API on Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775767/how-can-i-draw-an-image-from-the-html5-file-api-on-canvas)

Comment: Brilliant thanks, worked a treat. FYI, the picture.src came out as a blob path, something like `blob:<random-generated-string>`

Comment: Ideally, unless you're editing the image file, it's more memory efficient to use a thumbnail instead of the full file. URL.createObjectURL has to load the entire image file--which could be large. You can instead use StorageFile.getThumbnailAsync or getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync (Windows 8.1 only), and pass the result (a thumbnail) to URL.createObjectURL instead. Many images are larger than the whole display, so you can use these APIs to get a "thumbnail" that's sized to the screen, and be more memory efficient.